# Можно ли создать цикл for в цикле for?

Tags: php, циклы

Можно ли создать цикл `for` в цикле `for` в *PHP*?

Comment: Вадим, а почему бы вам не попробовать найти ответ экспериментальным путем? Что вас останавливает?

Comment: Пытаюсь решить задачку, не получается. Вот и подумал, что может это невозможно)

Comment: Вадим, в таком случае, спрашивайте о том, о чем хотите спросить. Объясните, чего вы хотели добиться, что вы для этого сделали (покажите код) и расскажите, что именно не получилось, Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего, проблема заключается в вечной ошибке всех новичков. Не понимая *сути* вызываемых команд, они просто их копируют. И получают одну и ту же переменную-счетчик, которая постоянно перезаписывается.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, надо понять, что `$i` - это не какой-то обязательный элемент синтаксиса `for`, а обычная *переменная*. У которой имя может быть любым, и которая должна использоваться только в одном контексте. Поэтому если у нас одна операция вложена в другую, то нельзя использовать переменную из внешнего цикла изменять внутри второго, и наоборот.

Так что решение очевидно - давать переменным-счетчикам разных циклов разные имена.

Answer (score 4):

Вложенные циклы доступны в *PHP*:

```
for ($a = 0; $a <=3; $a++) {
    for ($b = 0; $b <= 2; $b++) {
         print_r("a: $a, b: $b\n");
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
a: 0, b: 0
a: 0, b: 1
a: 0, b: 2
a: 1, b: 0
a: 1, b: 1
a: 1, b: 2
a: 2, b: 0
a: 2, b: 1
a: 2, b: 2
a: 3, b: 0
a: 3, b: 1
a: 3, b: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Да, [можно](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php).

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++) {

  }
}
```